# Is there a way to create swift frameworks like this?

Tags: ios, swift

The UIKit framework:

> import UIKit.NSAttributedString
>
> import UIKit.UIViewController

My question is how to create a custom framework which contains a lot of submodules like the UIKit framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a tutorial on how you can create modules in Swift](http://railsware.com/blog/2014/06/26/creation-of-pure-swift-module), but it doesn't talk about the extra magic on how to do submodules.

For that you need to dive into the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#submodule-declaration), which discusses how to declare modules and submodules.  [Apple's open source Module description says](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Modules.rst#id3):

> Warning
>
> This feature was never implemented, or even fully designed.